# How can delete default block of SonataUserBundle or SonataMediaBundle in SonataAdminbundle list?

Tags: symfony, yaml, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle, sonata-media-bundle

I do not know how can delete the default block of UserBundle, MediaBundle (just one of them...).

This is my config.yml:

```
    dashboard:
        blocks:

            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

#        groups:
#            sonata_page:
#                label: Taules
#                items:
#                    - sonata.admin.collection
#                    - sonata.admin.gender
#                    - sonata.admin.family
#                    - sonata.admin.color
#                    - sonata.admin.size
#                    - sonata.admin.article
```

And my security.yml:

```
security:
   encoders:
       FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SONATA_READER:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_VIEW
    ROLE_SONATA_EDITOR:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CREATE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDIT
    ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DELETE
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EXPORT
    ROLE_STAFF:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_READER]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_STAFF ,ROLE_SONATA_EDITOR, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the access to User and Media administration in the Sonata dashboard?

Comment: Yes but just one of them (user), please. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sonata AdminBundle security option to use the [Role Handler](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#role-handler), to let only one group the access to these administrations.

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to remove the block User to all users without  roles. I have only one user (admin). Thanks for your time.

Comment: If I can only do it with roles, how can I do it? Thanks again.